# How to use git to ignore some specific lines of a code on commit

Tags: javascript, git

For instance in this part of a code I need to ignore the line contain 'console.log' by git.
Is it possible to define a tag or something like this to inform git to ignore that?

```
this.service.doRequest(req).subscribe(
   onComplete => {
      this.subActions = onComplete;
      console.log('Container(actions) result:',this.subActions);   //need to ignore this line by git
   }, onError => {}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly exclude a line on commit itself.

You can use [`git add -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p) to add specific parts of your file (except the one you do not want), and then commit.

Comment: You can, however, use a "clean" filter to remove such lines (as you've noted in a few answers). The drawback is they'll never come back...

Comment: @torek of course, I immediately thought about that, but was unsure on how that would play in terms of compilation/execution, once the smudge  script has changed the source.